# Как перетасовать значения из бд

Tags: sql

Добрый день.
Нужно сделать пагинацию с рандомным значением людей.
Просто в sql rand указать не могу, т.к. один человек может попасть на несколько страниц.
Возможно ли как-то по дате/времени вывести рандомный список людей на странице или как-то ещё?
Спасибо

Comment: []()  

     RAND ( 100500 )  

Правда есть подозрение, что страницы будут одинаковы, пока количество записей в таблице неизменно.

Comment: прикол в том, что, допустим, я сперва выбираю страница 1 - вывелось 10 человек. Потом стр. 2 - вывелось ещё 10... но они не должны повториться, а это возможно

Comment: Мне кажется, что решить задачу можно, только если число строк в таблице фиксировано.  
Первоначально "инициализируете" пагинатор: определяете для него два числа- количество записей в таблице и "инициализатор рандома".  
Далее от страницы к странице передаете эти два числа и с их помощью определяете на какой странице какие записи показывать путем случайного перемешивания диапазона чисел на основе "инициализатора рандома".
Желательно еще иметь на клиенте этот самый массив как кэш.

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем понятно для всех ли пользователей один и тот же порядок (рандомный) должен быть, не совсем понятно должен ли порядок меняться по F5, не совсем понятно должен ли порядок меняться завтра или первая страница для одного и того же пользователя должна быть фиксированной...

В любом случае в качестве начального решения можно сделать:

```
order by md5(id+$seed)
```

где $seed может быть подставлен так, что реализуется сразу для нескольких вариантов.

Скорость вычисления md5, понятное дело, затормозит выборку, и скорее всего существенно, поэтому следует подумать об альтернативах.

Comment: хорошее решение :)